# Laravel HTML Jquery input by selecting image always return the highest value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this html code

```
<div class="gallery__item set-bg">
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset($template->image_path)}}" alt="" data-value="image-value">
<input type="hidden" id="image-value" name="selected_image" value="{{$template->id}}">
</div>
```

which rendered to this html

```
<img class="card-img-top highlighted" src="http://someurl.test/templates//1 (14).jpg" alt="" data-value="image-value">
<input type="hidden" id="image-value" name="selected_image" value="6">
</div>
```

I use this jquery

```
$('#select-form img').click(function() {
// Set the form value
$('#image-value').val($(this).attr('data-value'));

// Unhighlight all the images
$('#select-form img').removeClass('highlighted');

// Highlight the newly selected image
$(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
</script>
```

this is my laravel function

```
 // post template data
    public function postTemplate(Request $request)
    {
        $selected_image = $request->selected_image;
        dd($selected_image);

    }
```

the problem is the `$selected_image` always obtain the highest value in the page, what did I do wrong? and how to fix this please? thank you

note:the value on the html already change as expected if clicked

any clue will help..

Comment: I think you have multiple `selected_image` input on your page. Make sure you have only one `selected_image` input on your page (You shouldn't have one for every image).

Comment: @András thank you for your hint, it's true that I loop the images and all of them are `selected_image` but then how am I supposed to retrieve the value in the controller then if each one of them is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple `selected_image` inputs on your page. You also have to populate the `data-value` attributes of images with the appropriate id.
When a user clicks on the image, the jQuery code reads the `data-value` attribute of the selected image and sets the `value` of the `selected_image` field to that id.

Based on your jQuery script your code should look like this:

```html
<!-- Don't forget to modify the form's action attribute if necessary -->
<form id="select-form" method="POST" action="/template">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <!-- Put selected_image outside of the loop -->
    <input type="hidden" id="image-value" name="selected_image" value="">

    @foreach ($templates as $template)
        <div class="gallery__item set-bg">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset($template->image_path)}}" alt="" data-value="{{$template->id}}">
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

from Andras answer, I just edit a bit, it works

@csrf

```
            @foreach ($templates as $template)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mix story_f">
                <div class="gallery__item set-bg">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset($template->image_path)}}" alt="" data-value="{{$template->id}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <input type="hidden" id="image-value" name="selected_image" value="{{$template->id}}">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="site-btn">Preview Template</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```